# A dtype error occurs when using PPO with self defined env in stable baseline 3

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am trying to use a custom environment and run the PPO algorithm in Stable Baselines 3. The action_space and observation_space of my custom environment are both np.float32, and I printed the dtype of inputs and outputs for step and reset to confirm they are also np.float32. However, I encountered an error when running the following code. Is there any possible way to solve it?

My gymnasium version is 0.28.1, and my stable baseline 3 version is 2.0.0.

My env definition(I already pass the check_env(env) without any error or type warning):
self.action_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(64, ), dtype=np.float32)
self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(64, ), dtype=np.float32)

My Code is:
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)
model.predict(np.zeros(64, dtype=np.float32))

The error message is as follows:

````
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[8\], line 1
\----\> 1 model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/ppo/ppo.py:308, in PPO.learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, log_interval, tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar)
299 def learn(
300     self: SelfPPO,
301     total_timesteps: int,
(...)
306     progress_bar: bool = False,
307 ) -\> SelfPPO:
\--\> 308     return super().learn(
309         total_timesteps=total_timesteps,
310         callback=callback,
311         log_interval=log_interval,
312         tb_log_name=tb_log_name,
313         reset_num_timesteps=reset_num_timesteps,
314         progress_bar=progress_bar,
315     )

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py:259, in OnPolicyAlgorithm.learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, log_interval, tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar)
256 assert self.env is not None
258 while self.num_timesteps \< total_timesteps:
\--\> 259     continue_training = self.collect_rollouts(self.env, callback, self.rollout_buffer, n_rollout_steps=self.n_steps)
261     if continue_training is False:
262         break

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py:169, in OnPolicyAlgorithm.collect_rollouts(self, env, callback, rollout_buffer, n_rollout_steps)
166 with th.no_grad():
167     # Convert to pytorch tensor or to TensorDict
168     obs_tensor = obs_as_tensor(self.\_last_obs, self.device)
\--\> 169     actions, values, log_probs = self.policy(obs_tensor)
170 actions = actions.cpu().numpy()
172 # Rescale and perform action

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module.\_call_impl(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
1497 # this function, and just call forward.
1498 if not (self.\_backward_hooks or self.\_backward_pre_hooks or self.\_forward_hooks or self.\_forward_pre_hooks
1499         or \_global_backward_pre_hooks or \_global_backward_hooks
1500         or \_global_forward_hooks or \_global_forward_pre_hooks):
\-\> 1501     return forward_call(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = \[\], \[\]

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/policies.py:620, in ActorCriticPolicy.forward(self, obs, deterministic)
618 features = self.extract_features(obs)
619 if self.share_features_extractor:
\--\> 620     latent_pi, latent_vf = self.mlp_extractor(features)
621 else:
622     pi_features, vf_features = features

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module.\_call_impl(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
1497 # this function, and just call forward.
1498 if not (self.\_backward_hooks or self.\_backward_pre_hooks or self.\_forward_hooks or self.\_forward_pre_hooks
1499         or \_global_backward_pre_hooks or \_global_backward_hooks
1500         or \_global_forward_hooks or \_global_forward_pre_hooks):
\-\> 1501     return forward_call(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = \[\], \[\]

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/torch_layers.py:222, in MlpExtractor.forward(self, features)
217 def forward(self, features: th.Tensor) -\> Tuple\[th.Tensor, th.Tensor\]:
218     """
219     :return: latent_policy, latent_value of the specified network.
220         If all layers are shared, then ``latent_policy == latent_value``
221     """
\--\> 222     return self.forward_actor(features), self.forward_critic(features)

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/torch_layers.py:225, in MlpExtractor.forward_actor(self, features)
224 def forward_actor(self, features: th.Tensor) -\> th.Tensor:
\--\> 225     return self.policy_net(features)

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module.\_call_impl(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
1497 # this function, and just call forward.
1498 if not (self.\_backward_hooks or self.\_backward_pre_hooks or self.\_forward_hooks or self.\_forward_pre_hooks
1499         or \_global_backward_pre_hooks or \_global_backward_hooks
1500         or \_global_forward_hooks or \_global_forward_pre_hooks):
\-\> 1501     return forward_call(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = \[\], \[\]

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py:217, in Sequential.forward(self, input)
215 def forward(self, input):
216     for module in self:
\--\> 217         input = module(input)
218     return input

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module.\_call_impl(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
1497 # this function, and just call forward.
1498 if not (self.\_backward_hooks or self.\_backward_pre_hooks or self.\_forward_hooks or self.\_forward_pre_hooks
1499         or \_global_backward_pre_hooks or \_global_backward_hooks
1500         or \_global_forward_hooks or \_global_forward_pre_hooks):
\-\> 1501     return forward_call(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = \[\], \[\]

File \~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py:114, in Linear.forward(self, input)
113 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -\> Tensor:
\--\> 114     return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype```

I watch the traceback, and it shows that there is a function self.mlp_extractor.forward_actor(features). The dtype of its output is np.float32, but the following code need np.float64. After I change the function extract_features in policies.py from:


    preprocessed_obs = preprocess_obs(obs,self.observation_space,normalize_images=self.normalize_images)
    return features_extractor(preprocessed_obs)



to:

    preprocessed_obs = preprocess_obs(obs, self.observation_space, normalize_images=self.normalize_images)
    preprocessed_obs = preprocessed_obs.to(th.float64)
    return features_extractor(preprocessed_obs)

The above problem was fixed(model.predict works), but it occurred a new problem when I run model.learn:

`RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/ppo/ppo.py:308, in PPO.learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, log_interval, tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar)
    299 def learn(
    300     self: SelfPPO,
    301     total_timesteps: int,
   (...)
    306     progress_bar: bool = False,
    307 ) -> SelfPPO:
--> 308     return super().learn(
    309         total_timesteps=total_timesteps,
    310         callback=callback,
    311         log_interval=log_interval,
    312         tb_log_name=tb_log_name,
    313         reset_num_timesteps=reset_num_timesteps,
    314         progress_bar=progress_bar,
    315     )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py:281, in OnPolicyAlgorithm.learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, log_interval, tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar)
    278         self.logger.record("time/total_timesteps", self.num_timesteps, exclude="tensorboard")
    279         self.logger.dump(step=self.num_timesteps)
--> 281     self.train()
    283 callback.on_training_end()
    285 return self

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stable_baselines3/ppo/ppo.py:272, in PPO.train(self)
    270 # Optimization step
    271 self.policy.optimizer.zero_grad()
--> 272 loss.backward()
    273 # Clip grad norm
    274 th.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.policy.parameters(), self.max_grad_norm)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py:487, in Tensor.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    477 if has_torch_function_unary(self):
    478     return handle_torch_function(
    479         Tensor.backward,
    480         (self,),
   (...)
    485         inputs=inputs,
    486     )
--> 487 torch.autograd.backward(
    488     self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs
    489 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:200, in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    195     retain_graph = create_graph
    197 # The reason we repeat same the comment below is that
    198 # some Python versions print out the first line of a multi-line function
    199 # calls in the traceback and some print out the last line
--> 200 Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    201     tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
    202     allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)

RuntimeError: Found dtype Float but expected Double```
````